# Code Coverage Report for AWS Lambda Integration test using Python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, integration-testing

I have written integration tests for lambdas that hit the dev site (in AWS). The tests are working fine. Tests are written in a separate project that uses a request object to hit the endpoint to validate the result.

Currently, I am running all the tests from my local. Lambdas are deployed using a separate Jenkins job.

However, I need to generate a code coverage report for these tests. I am not sure how I can generate the code coverage report as I am directly hitting the dev URL from my local. I am using Python 3.8.

All the lambdas have lambda layers which provide a database connection and some other common business logic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Code coverage is probably not the right metric for integration tests. As far as I can tell you use integration tests to test your requirements/use cases/user stories.

Imagine you have an application with a shopping cart feature. A user has 10 items in that shopping cart and now deletes one of those items. Your integration test would make sure that after this operation only (the correct) 9 items are left in the shopping cart.

For this kind of testing it is not relevant which/how much code was run. It is more like a black box test. You want to know that for a given "action" the correct "state" is created.

Code coverage is usually something you use with unit tests. For integration tests I think you want to know how many of your requirements/use cases/user stories are covered.

Comment: I agree with your comment. We don't have unit tests written for the lambdas. However, we need to show generate some percentage code is covered by our API/integration testing. The unit tests might take some more time to write at this point.

Comment: @user2026504 I don't know enough about the Python ecosystem to know if there is anything that can help you here. That said, Amazon recently announced a new Lambda feature that might help you with this: [Lambda Extensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-extensions-api.html). They also just announced the possibility to launch a [Docker image (from ECR) as Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-images.html). So maybe you can build an image which contains some tool to create the code coverage report, when the Lambda is invoked. Hope that helps.

Comment: Writing unit test can be also challenging here, as all the lambdas use at least one layer which provides database connection and some other common business logic functions. So not sure if I can run the just .py files in a lambda with pytest or I have to invoke lambda there too so it can get all references of lambda layers. It's a separate question maybe. Unfortunately, I don't find any guidelines from AWS on how to write a unit test for lambdas with multiple layers using python, not for code coverage for api testing too.

Comment: Sure, Jens. Let me read the links and see if it provides some guidelines. I am already using Docker for local debugging and development using AWS SAM.